# SwiperJS - ReactJS carousel mixed with videos and images double sounded

Tags: reactjs, dom, swiper.js

I'm using the `SwiperJS` in a `NextJS` project that contains a mixed slide content. I'm facing a double sound problem with the react-youtube component.

My swiper configurations uses the `loop:true`, but I figured out that this is what is causing the double sound, because all slides are duplicated. Than when the active slide is the video I set him to play, but that causes the duplicated slide play also.

If I remove the  `loop:true`, it works fine. But I need maintain the  `loop:true` on my project.

---

One solution that I tried but didn't have any effect was to find the Swiper Carousel wrapper and then get an iframe array, which I get the position 1 that is the duplicated video to try to stop him from playing

```
document.querySelector('[id^="Main_Carousel"]')
.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1]
.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'command', func: 'stopVideo' }), '*');
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs (https://swiperjs.com/react#swiper-slide-props) the SwiperSlide contains an `isDuplicate` property.  You could check for that before playing the video.